# how to add ip routes with host name instead of ip address?

Tags: dns, hosts, network

I want to add IP routes for host that I do not have the IP address for. 
I basically want tell macOS to search for a host in a specific interface:

```
sudo route add -host <myHostname> -iface en7
```

Background: 
I have set up WiFi to be my primary network interface. But I want to be able to access host that are only available in the wired network with the interface `en7`. Therefore I wanted to add such a route to the system.

The command above results in the error: `route: bad address: myHostname`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can't do this; this is not the way IP routing works.**

[DNS is name resolution.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System)  It's nothing more than an address book of names pointing to some numbers (IPs)

```
myhost.com --------> 111.222.333.444
```

DNS tells you what the address is, not how to get there.  [IP routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_routing) is the mechanism of how you get from one point to the next.  It's the same difference between "Contacts" and "Maps" in your iPhone.

> I basically want tell macOS to search for a host in a specific
>   interface:

You can't tell an interface what "hosts" (names) are there.  You tell it what networks are accessible.  Networks are defined by IP address(es).

For instance:

- `en0` has an IP of `192.168.1.4` and is on the network `192.168.1.0/24`
- `en1` has an IP of `10.0.0.9` and is is on the network `10.0.0.0/24`
- A subnetwork, `10.0.5.0/24` is attached (via switch) on the `10.0.0.0/24` network

  ```
   en0+------------> 192.168.1.0/24


   en1+------------> 10.0.0.0/24
                               +
                               |
                               +------> 10.0.5.0/24
  ```

Now, you add a host called `foo.bar` in DNS and it has an IP address of `10.0.0.12`.  Your system will know to go through interface `en1` to get to it.

If another host, called `foobar.foo` had an IP address of `10.0.5.12`, again, it would know to go through `en1` because that route would be defined.

To accomplish what you're looking to do, your host has to be able to get name resolution across two separate domains (not interfaces).  You can accomplish this two ways:

- update your hosts file manually
- [have a multi-horizon DNS server (aware of both domains/networks)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/316315/119271)

Comment: Some details of the answer are wrong: 1. the IP-address 111.222.333.444 ;-). 2. 10.0.5.0/24 is no subnetwork of 10.0.0.0/24. A route from the second to the first doesn't really exist. Proper networks would be 10.0.0.0/8-10.0.0.0/21 (all include 10.0.5.0/24).

Answer (score 0):

this is quite late response, but I just did what you've asked and it works for me.

I'm using VPN connection to get access to my office which is running on ppp0 interface. I've run below and now I can access hostnames which are only available via vpn, without setting up option to send all traffic through VPN.

/sbin/route add -host  -interface

Answer (score -1):

To the best of my knowledge setting a default next hop or interface for hostnames instead of IP addresses isn't possible.

Is there a reason you aren't creating a route pointing to the next hop or interface for the wired accessible subnet(s) instead?